# Why can't I add components to my JFrame (Java Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Please excuse me if my code is awful. First time learning Swing and generally clueless at Java generally; still trying to learn Java and also thought I'd add a UI component to make it more challenging.

I have a recurring error that I cannot figure out.

Firstly, the current code will launch (called from Main file) but doesn't have the components within the Window (I.e., it launches with a blank window), so I have begun adding the components to my JFrame (see 'frame.add()', located at the start of initComponents()). When trying to add components I get this error:

Error: "Cannot read field "parent" because "comp" is null"

Is this due to the lack of event handling? I intended to try and get it working then add that functionality later. See below. Or is this caused by something else?

```java
public class UserInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JFrame frame;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_One;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Two;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Three;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Four;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Five;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Six;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Seven;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Eight;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Nine;
    private java.awt.Button button_Number_Zero;
    private java.awt.Button back_Button1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

    public void starter() {
        initComponents();
        new UserInterface().setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        frame.add(jLabel1);

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Result:");

        button_Number_One = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_One.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_One.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_One_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Two = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Two.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Two.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Two_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Three = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Three.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Three.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Three_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Four = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Four.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Four.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Four_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Five = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Five.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Five.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Five_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Six = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Six.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Six.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Six_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Seven = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Seven.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Seven.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Seven_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Eight = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Eight.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Eight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Eight_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Nine = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Nine.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Nine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Nine_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        button_Number_Zero = new java.awt.Button();
        button_Number_Zero.setLabel("1");
        button_Number_Zero.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_Number_Zero_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        back_Button1 = new java.awt.Button();
        back_Button1.setLabel("Back");
        back_Button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                back_Button1_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        // jLabel1.setText("Result: ");

        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu1.setText("File");
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void button_Number_One_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Two_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Three_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Four_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Five_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Six_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Seven_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Eight_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Nine_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void button_Number_Zero_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void back_Button1_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

    private void jTextField_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Event handling code here.
    }

}
```

Comment: *First time learning Swing...* - 1) so why would you write a 100 lines of code first before testing? Start slowly. Add a couple of components and test. Once that works add more. 2) Don't use "Button", that is an AWT component. Swing components start with "J" so you should be using `JButton`. Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for working examples that will help you better structure your code.

Comment: *"..clueless at Java generally; still trying to learn Java and also thought I'd add a UI component to make it more challenging."* For who? For us sorting the mess of code posted, rife with misunderstandings that a programmer should be past before attempting to make multi-threaded, event driven,  cross platform GUIs? I suggest sticking with non-GUI apps until you don't have to write *"clueless at Java generally"*.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `null` component to the frame. Judging from your code this is likely one of the components that you have not initialised.

For example in this part of your code

```
frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
// You first add the label which is not initialised at this point and is therefore null
frame.add(jLabel1); 

// You must initialise the label before adding it to the frame.
jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel1.setText("Result:");
```

Also some other notes:

- When posting errors, include the full stacktrace so people can help u most effectively.
- Lookup naming conventions in Java
- Lookup how to import stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code which will add `jLabel1` in the `JFrame`, The remaining components you have to add into the frame as per your requirements.
The error was related to that you are adding the component into the frame before initializing that is why it throws a null pointer exception.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class UserInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  private Button button_Number_One;
  private Button button_Number_Two;
  private Button button_Number_Three;
  private Button button_Number_Four;
  private Button button_Number_Five;
  private Button button_Number_Six;
  private Button button_Number_Seven;
  private Button button_Number_Eight;
  private Button button_Number_Nine;
  private Button button_Number_Zero;
  private Button back_Button1;
  private JLabel jLabel1;
  private JMenu jMenu1;
  private JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
  private JTextField jTextField1;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new UserInterface().starter();
  }

  public void starter() {
    initComponents();
    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    jLabel1.setText("Result:");

    this.add(jLabel1);

    jTextField1 = new JTextField();
    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        jTextField_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

//    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
//    jLabel1.setText("Result:");

    button_Number_One = new Button();
    button_Number_One.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_One.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_One_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Two = new Button();
    button_Number_Two.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Two.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Two_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Three = new Button();
    button_Number_Three.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Three.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Three_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Four = new Button();
    button_Number_Four.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Four.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Four_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Five = new Button();
    button_Number_Five.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Five.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Five_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Six = new Button();
    button_Number_Six.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Six.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Six_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Seven = new Button();
    button_Number_Seven.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Seven_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Eight = new Button();
    button_Number_Eight.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Eight_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Nine = new Button();
    button_Number_Nine.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Nine_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    button_Number_Zero = new Button();
    button_Number_Zero.setLabel("1");
    button_Number_Zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button_Number_Zero_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    back_Button1 = new Button();
    back_Button1.setLabel("Back");
    back_Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        back_Button1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    // jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    // jLabel1.setText("Result: ");

    jMenu1 = new JMenu();
    jMenu1.setText("File");
    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  private void button_Number_One_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Two_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Three_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Four_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Five_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Six_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Seven_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Eight_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Nine_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void button_Number_Zero_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void back_Button1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

  private void jTextField_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Event handling code here.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `UserInterface` extends the `JFrame` class, therefore it inherits all of `JFrame`'s functionality.  What you're doing there is defining a special type of `JFrame` for your own purposes, so it doesn't really make sense to me to create a `JFrame` within your own implementation of one. That might be your issue, as the parent class would be referring to `JFrame`.  I would suggest trying to work with a standard `JFrame` and adding your Buttons, labels, etc. to it first.